# How to change a toolbar item (logo) for different theme

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a question. I need to have few toolbar items related to different styles. I have created Theme Resources and with the help of settings plugin I am saving different themes. However I would also like to have different toolbar items dedicated for each theme. I have tried to add my image in Resource dictionary like this

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <Image x:Key="logo" Source="IconSettings.png"></Image>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

and then in Xaml use it like this

```
   <ToolbarItem IconImageSource="{DynamicResource logo}"/>
```

But nothing is displayed. Do you maybe have any suggestions even different approach?

Also have tried to follow this solution https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/152758/setting-icon-file-names-as-resources

Comment: I think you can try to change the IconImageSource in code behind when you change the theme. Use messagingCenter to notify the ToolbarItems.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/152758/setting-icon-file-names-as-resources) you provided, why don't you try something like this

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <x:String x:Key="logo">IconSettings.png</x:String>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And use it in your XAML.

You were trying to add `image` at the place of `string input`, that's the reason it showed you nothing

Let me know if its working fine or not

Comment: Hello, I have tried it but it doesn't display icons on iOS, instead there is white space

Comment: yes it did, on android it works well. Now I can see it even on Its however it doesn't update when I change my theme, only if I switch off and on the application.